# If $j:X \to Y$ is surjective then so is $j_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Trying to simplify the isomorphism proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306270/show-the-quotient-map-s1-times-s1-rightarrow-s2-collapsing-the-subspace/2916828#2916828), is it not the case that in the following section of the long exact sequence:

$$ \dots \to H_2(S^1\vee S^1)\xrightarrow{i_*} H_2(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{j_*} H_2(S^1\times S^1/S^1\vee S^1) \to \dots$$

**we have that, since $j_*$ is obtained from a surjective map $j$ (the quotient map), $j_*$ is surjective as well? (proof: for $[\alpha]\in H_n(Y)$ we can always choose $[j^{-1}\cdot\alpha]\in H_n(X)$?)**

Then all is left is to show that $img(i_*)=0$ since, by exactness, we would then get that $ker(j_*)=img(i_*)=0$ so it must also be injective (and this is obvious since $img(i_*)=0$ follows from $H_2(S^1\vee S^1)=0$).

Comment: The claim is false. What does $j^{-1}\cdot\alpha$ mean?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Oh, I mistakenly assumed it was bijective, and then: if $\alpha : \Delta^n \to Y$ and $j: X \to Y$ then the composition $j^{-1} \circ \alpha$ is a continuous map from $\Delta^n \to X$, i.e. a singular $n$-simplex

Comment: Consider the surjection $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$.

Comment: @Anon: If $j$ is continuous with continuous inverse (as you're assuming), then $j$ is a homeomorphism, in which case $j_*$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your claim is a general claim that says "given a quotient map $q: X \to Y$, the induced map on homology $q_*: H_*(X) \to H_*(Y)$ is surjective."

This is false. For example, consider the quotient map $q: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$. On $H_1$ this map is $q_*: 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which of course cannot be surjective.

If you want to modify the claim and say instead that $q_*$ must be a surjection on top-dimensional homology (say, take $X$ and $Y$ to be CW complexes so that "dimension" makes sense), this is still false, witnessed by the quotient map $q: S^3 \to \mathbb{R}P^3$ which induces the multiplication-by-$2$ map on $H_3$.